# AWS Lambda /var/task classpath

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, gwt, classpath, agent

I am having a problem with no possibility to save files into a /var/task filesystem.
If I understand it right, the classpath of lambda is /var/task. I am running a gwt agent in lambda, but it looks for specific file in a classpath. The problem is, that the files that need to be compiled are saved in /var/tmp. So to gwt agent gives an error.
*"Unable to find *file.xml.gwt* on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?"*

Comment: Please provide the source code of your lambda function

Comment: Sorry, I cannot provide a source code because it is fro my job.
I need to know, if is possible to set a different path for GWT Agent to look for, because according to AWS, there is no way to make /var/task writable. Unfortunately I was not able to find the info about changing the searching path of the GWT agent.

Comment: It is not expected to provide a real example, just a sample that explains the problem you are having.